# Bootstrap - scroll only one column when both are set to overflow:auto;

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a page layout in Bootstrap where I have a sidebar column and a content column. I have both columns set to `height:100%;` and `overflow:auto;` so that the sidebar stays in place while the content column can be scrolled.

I want to add some jQuery to scroll to certain areas in the content column when a link is clicked, but the script I usually use for this is not working due to the `overflow:auto;`

Here is my script:

```
function scrollToLink(id){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
  }, 2000);
}

$(function() {
  $("#sidebar a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollToLink(this.href.split("#")[1]);  
  });
});
```

And [here is the Bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/KWZWe8ACbP)

To see the effect I am going for, remove the `column` class(which is what sets the `height` and `overflow` properties) from the `col-sm-9` element and then click on the "Up Next" link in the sidebar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `scrollToLink()` with this:

```
function scrollToLink(id){
  var target = $(window).width() > 767 ? $('#main') : $('body');
  target.animate({
    scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
  }, 2000);
}
```

You also have some responsiveness issues. You should wrap the "columns" layout CSS rules in a `@media (min-width: 767px)` query.